# Okular freezes attempting to open more than one document

Tags: lubuntu, okular

I installed Okular in Lubuntu 20.04 (x64).

Opening a file in Okular works with no problems. However, if I click any other document whose format (pdf, djvu, whatever) is associated with Okular in file manager, the second Okular instance opens only to freeze instantly. I have no choice, but to kill it. The first instance remains responsive and behaves normally all the time.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the behavior similar to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/okular/+bug/1248461) bug?

Comment: @AntoniosP. No, it is some thing else entirely (the file attached to the bug opens without any difficulties).

Comment: I tried to re-create your issue but was unable to. My `pcmanfm-qt` is linked with `qpdfview` (the default for Lubuntu) but I was able to open multiple documents using `okular` (and page up and down in any of 3 documents I opened with multiple pages).  Is it `pcmanfm-qt` that you mean by file manager, did you change defaults for pdf etc.. Are their any clues in `dmesg` or `journalctl`?

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your try! I open documents by clicking the file name in either pcmanfm-qt or file manager called Double commander (also, I tried to open it directly from Okular using File / Open). No matter what is the method, it always works as described above. Qpdfview works no better for me (and so does Djview for djvu-files). Aren't they all use the same Poppler library to render pdf and djvu? Could it be a library problem?

Important update: it seems not to freeze, actually, it is just working unbelievably slowly (it takes about half an hour for a file of 3-4 MB to open).

Comment: @guiverc I am not sure I know how to use dmesg or journalctl to track the problem's root. Could you please elaborate a bit on that? What exactly should I look for in ouput of those commands?

Comment: To use `dmesg` open a terminal and type `dmesg`. (it'll just scroll all logs since boot on your terminal).  Normally I'd `grep` or `less` (to page output, or old unix type searches introduced ~1969).   `journalctl` opens with a pager but will use same searching that existed pre-mouse days (with same search functions in all unix inc `vi` or modern `vim`; use '/' key etc)   I would compare output of normal runs, to what occurs in output when it gives trouble (ie. is anything new there, I'd not expect any output during a normal `qpdfview` run in either log, maybe there will be some with issues)